Sending events in React from a parent to a child component
I would like to forward some custom events from a parent React component to some children components, so that they can make a decision based on the event received without the parent having to directly manage the state of the children.
This is a reduced example to show the idea that I was trying out.
ParentControl.tsx
export default function ParentControl() {
    const divRef = useRef<HTMLDivElement>(null);

    const dispatchEvent = (e: CustomEvent) => {
        divRef.current.dispatchEvent(e);
    };  

    return (
        <div ref={divRef} >
            <Child name="Child1" dispatcher={divRef} />
            <Child name="Child2" dispatcher={divRef} />

            <button onClick={() => dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent('prev', {detail: ''})) }>
                Prev
            </button>
            <button onClick={() => dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent('next', {detail: ''})) }>
                Next
            </button>
        </div>
    );  
}


Child.tsx
export type ChildProps = {
    name: string;
    dispatcher: RefObject<HTMLElement>;
};

export default function Child({ name, dispatcher }: ChildProps) {
    const [index, setIndex] = useState(0);

    const selectPrev = (event: CustomEvent) => {
        console.log(`Received event: ${event.type}, index: ${index}`);
        setIndex(index - 1);
    };  

    const selectNext = (event: CustomEvent) => {
        console.log(`Received event: ${event.type}, index: ${index}`);
        setIndex(index + 1);
    };  

    const printState = () => {
        console.log(`printState(): index: ${index}`);
    };  

    useEffect(() => {
        const dispatch = dispatcher.current;

        dispatch.addEventListener("next", selectNext);
        dispatch.addEventListener("prev", selectPrev);

        return () => {
            dispatch.removeEventListener("next", selectNext);
            dispatch.removeEventListener("prev", selectPrev);
        };  
    }, []);

    return (
        <div>
            <div>
                {name} Index: {index}
            </div>
            <button onClick={() => printState()}>Print</button>
        </div>
    );  
}

Running this I see that the selectNext() and selectPrev() methods are indeed called when the parent component dispatches an event, however these methods can only see the initial index state = 0 within the child, so they can only change the index to -1 or 1. How can these callbacks see the real current state of the child?
Is it possible to accomplish this somehow using events (that may later include multiple types) without having to use the React's Context API?

Your useEffect deps is an empty array ([]). It's generally an indication of a problem if a variable is referenced inside an effect and is not included in the deps array (selectNext and selectPrev). That's because any closures used inside the effect that aren't referenced in the deps can be stale and hold stale values. Currently, the selectPrev and selectNext from the initial render is held in memory, and those closures also reference the values as they were when the closure was created.
You can use the official ESLint plugin to catch these problems at compile time.
Your code can be fixed by adding them to the useEffect deps. Note, since they would otherwise change on every render, I've also wrapped the methods in useCallback and put index in the deps array there. That means those closures are refreshed only when the index changes. This in turn will refresh the effect.
  const selectPrev = useCallback(
    (event: CustomEvent) => {
      console.log(`Received event: ${event.type}, index: ${index}`);
      setIndex(index - 1);
    },
    [index]
  );

  const selectNext = useCallback(
    (event: CustomEvent) => {
      console.log(`Received event: ${event.type}, index: ${index}`);
      setIndex(index + 1);
    },
    [index]
  );

  const printState = () => {
    console.log(`printState(): index: ${index}`);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    const dispatch = dispatcher.current;

    dispatch.addEventListener("next", selectNext);
    dispatch.addEventListener("prev", selectPrev);

    return () => {
      dispatch.removeEventListener("next", selectNext);
      dispatch.removeEventListener("prev", selectPrev);
    };
  }, [selectPrev, selectNext]);

However this will deregister/register the event handlers each time. You can instead approach it by using the callback form of the state setter, which will always be supplied the latest value.
  const selectPrev = 
    (event: CustomEvent) => {
      console.log(`Received event: ${event.type}, index: ${index}`);
      setIndex((index) =>  index - 1);
    }

  const selectNext = 
    (event: CustomEvent) => {
      console.log(`Received event: ${event.type}, index: ${index}`);
      setIndex((index) => index + 1);
    }

  const printState = () => {
    console.log(`printState(): index: ${index}`);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    const dispatch = dispatcher.current;

    // @ts-ignore
    dispatch.addEventListener("next", selectNext);
    // @ts-ignore
    dispatch.addEventListener("prev", selectPrev);

    return () => {
      dispatch.removeEventListener("next", selectNext);
      dispatch.removeEventListener("prev", selectPrev);
    };
  }, []);

However I have to stress what you are doing is considered a very odd pattern in React, for two primary reasons:

The general goal of wanting components to manage their own state, but sync that state based on control logic in some parent is usually solved by hoisting the state. That is the most idiomatic solution. It would be good to know about your use case and driver for not doing that. Possibly there is a legit reason, hence the "usually". This doesn't necessarily need to be context. You could just have a custom hook that has the state in and have that provide the props to spread to each child. This answer can be improved drastically if we can understand the reasoning behind needing this mechanism.
Dispatching events on the DOM element is a bit of an abuse of that mechanism. That generally isn't supposed to be used as a "free event bus". For one, it has semantics/heuristics that don't make sense as a general purpose event bus. You should probably pass down a simple event bus impl that has nothing to do with the DOM. Also, what you are trying to do might be better served by useImperativeHandle.


Yeh! Though this is a common use case and actually the right thing to do (https://react.dev/learn/separating-events-from-effects#effects-run-whenever-synchronization-is-needed) , even though it feels a bit weird. Its the general event bus approach which causes that extra cruft. If you have more details on my first bullet I can give more targetted advice :).

Thank you, this is a useful response. A downside is that the event listeners are deregistered and re-registered every time that the state changes. In my case hoisting the state is not great, because I can have multiple children those state is a detail that the control doesn't need to know about. The control may actually end up not being a direct parent later on. My idea is that each child will have an associated document fetched separately once and then display only the relevant data depending on the actions of the controller.

Ive just edited with a solution that doesnt require the event bus de/re registering.

I'd like to upvote you but I get a validation error: "You need at least 15 reputation to cast a vote, but your feedback has been recorded.". I hope someone else will upvote your answer. Many thanks.

No worries! In regards to "because I can have multiple children those state is a detail that the control doesn't need to know about." I think there is a mental-model problem here. The problem you described is best solved with context. However, specifically, the "control" logic would exist in a wrapped Context provider. So none of the details of that state or how its managed would leak out. Youd just have a <MyThingyProvider> which can be moved anywhere in the tree.

For example, in many libraries that require it, it is normal that they export a pre-baked provider that encapsulates core state and state logic that the consumer simply drops in where they want in the JSX. The logic is therefore portable.

In other words: You shouldnt view the DOM tree as an escape hatch to pass events down. For one its unreliable. Portalled components would not see those events (usually modals etc). Since DOM tree is not necessarily a mirror hierarchy to the component tree. Secondly, it does not provide any scoping advantage (anything can hook into those events along the way).

Sorry to be picky, but the log index: ${index} will always be 0 without having [index] in the last solution. This is a small detail, but later on I intended to do some checks on the new index before setting it to ensure it's within a valid range, so I cannot use the setIndex((index) =>  ... version. Anyway this is a good step forward even if I cannot avoid registering and deregistering multiple times.

Thats correct. Though you could put the logging in the state set callback though thats hacky. The actual idiomatic way of solving this problem in React (ignoring the wider convo above) is actually to de/reregister events. Though this indeed does feel weird at first.

You can still do checks/clamps on the value though since you can put the conditional logic inside the callback.

I think I'll try the approach that you suggested introducing a React Context, however I believe the provider needs to be a direct parent, but I can make it work. I see your point that my approach is a bit of an escape route from the "react way".

Context should work at any level, but obviously where it is "scoped" to will also define behaviour. If you wanted a constraint that it should be a direct parent, you could actually use cloneElement instead of context (though usually, having such constraints is annoying to consumers since it breaks when you simply want to wrap something).

One final point. https://jotai.org/ and https://github.com/pmndrs/zustand may be interesting to you.
